# Grading Students Hackerrank challenge return expected?

Tags: javascript

Anyone who is familiar with the Grading students challenge on [Hackerank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/grading/problem?isFullScreen=true), please help me understand why this code is not passing.

```
function gradingStudents(grades) {
  let args = [...arguments];
  const round5 = (x) => {
    return Math.ceil(x / 5) * 5;
  }
  for (let i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (round5(args[i]) - args[i] < 3 && args[i] >= 38) {
      args[i] = round5(args[i])
    }
  }
  args.shift()
  return args.join('\n') + '\n'
//return args
//return args.join(' ')
}
```

I am losing my mind. I have tried all sorts of returns and none works.

Comment: Why do you need `args` when you're receiving the grades as arguments? When looking at the assignment, you're expected to return an array, not a string. Finally, your rounding logic is incorrect too. As is your array handling.

Comment: _"help me understand why this code is not passing"_... we can't do that unless you also include the passing criteria. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Hi @Phil, you are right, my bad I should have included what is the expected output.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I was using `args` because the challenge states *The first line contains a single integer, n, the number of students.* 

So I assumed I am getting an array where the first element is the number of students. But it seems that is not the case.

The rounding logic is okay though. I just misunderstood what was the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you thought that both the number of students and the grades are being passed to the `gradingStudents` function, but actually *only* a single argument is being passed i.e. an array containing the `grades` of the students.

So, no need to use `arguments`, you can directly use the `grades` array. And also you simply need to return the updated grades array from the function, you don't need to worry about output formatting.

```js
function gradingStudents(grades) {
  const round5 = (x) => {
    return Math.ceil(x / 5) * 5;
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    if (round5(grades[i]) - grades[i] < 3 && grades[i] >= 38) {
      grades[i] = round5(grades[i]);
    }
  }
  return grades;
}

console.log(gradingStudents([73, 67, 38, 33]));
```

Comment: HI @SSM, that did not work, I got the error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Array`

Comment: @Ben How is that possible? I verified it on HackerRank, did you remove any other code that is present by default?

Comment: @Ben Verified it again, you must have removed something other than the function which is why it's breaking. There's a reset code button on top right corner use that and try again, it should work!

Comment: You are right. I must have tinkered with something. Your code works. Now let me understand the logic

Comment: turns out the `grades` is the array to work on. The *sample input 0* is what confused me because I assumed the input also included the number of students. But I have console logged the grades at the start of the function and I have seen that it is just the array of grades `[ 73, 67, 38, 33 ]`. 

I will make `console.log `my friend.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this problem and found a cleaner solution if anybody is interested.

```
function gradingStudents(grades) {
    let newArray = grades.map(num => (num >= 38 && num % 5 >= 3) ? num + 5 -(num % 5) : num);
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

all. Here is the most compact and easy-to-understand code for the said problem.

```
for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) { 
    let mod5=grades[i]%5;       
    if ((grades[i] >= 38)&&(mod5>=3)){
        grades[i]=grades[i]+(5-(mod5));
    }
}
return grades;
```

Comment: If you need any help to understand the code you can write comment here.